# How would one convert the cartesian expression y=1/x to polar form?

Tags: polar-coordinates

How would one convert the cartesian expression y=1/x to polar form? I'd really appreciate a step-by-step solution so I can apply the same principle to other problems. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition x=rcosθ ,y=rsinθ. where r is the radial distance from the origin, and theta is the counterclockwise angle from the x-axis. In terms of x and  y $$r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$ and $$θ=tan^{-1}{(y/x)}$$ Can you do the substitution?

Answer (score 1):

Just substitute $x=r \cos \theta$ and $y=r \sin \theta$:
$$
y=1/x \rightarrow r \sin \theta=\frac{1}{r \cos \theta}\rightarrow r^2=\frac{1}{ \sin \theta \cos \theta}=\frac{2}{ \sin 2\theta}
$$
so:
$$
r=\pm\sqrt{\frac{2}{ \sin 2\theta}}
$$

Comment: Negative $r$? Sure?

Comment: @egreg maybe in this case is redundant

Comment: The graph of $r = -\sqrt{2/\sin(2\theta)}$ is replicated by the graph of $r = \sqrt{2/\sin(2\theta)}$, just $\pi$ radians out of phase (somewhat like the way the graph of $r=1$ replicates the graph of $r=-1$). I suppose the answer depends on whether you want an equation satisfied by the same set of points in the coordinate plane, or whether you want a solution set for converting a particular pair of $x,y$ coordinates to $r,\theta$.